# Streaming songs from pc

Tags: audio, web, streaming, mp3, audio-streaming

i wanted to create a project which :

a) Will have a list of MP3 file with each of their length.
b) Now i want to stream them
c) Using the timer the sound track will be new one after sudden interval.
d) and it should be accessible in the form like http://localhost:1024/livemusic

Like we find in live streaming web sites.if the song is accessible in URL form i guess it will be accessible via mobile phone too.

what would be the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source or commercial streaming platform

- http://icecast.org
- http://ampache.org
- http://www.videolan.org
- https://obsproject.com